# How can we find E(X^n) for a discrete random variable X in R?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, weighted-average

Suppose values of a discrete random variable X, `randomNumbers`, and its distribution `prob` is given.

I can find ***E(X)*** using the following code:

```
weighted.mean(randomNumbers, prob)
```

How can we find ***E(X^n)*** in R?

Would this code work?

```
weighted.mean(randomNumbers^n, prob)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take Poisson random variable `X ~ Poisson(2)` for example.

### probabilistic method

```
f1 <- function (N) {
  x <- 0:N
  p <- dpois(x, 2)
  ## approximate E[X]
  m1 <- weighted.mean(x, p)
  ## approximate E[X ^ 2]
  m2 <- weighted.mean(x ^ 2, p)
  ## approximate E[X ^ 3]
  m3 <- weighted.mean(x ^ 3, p)
  ## return
  c(m1, m2, m3)
  }
```

As `N` gets bigger, **approximation** is more and more accurate, in the sense that the sequence converges analytically.

```
N <- seq(10, 200, 10)
m123_prob <- t(sapply(N, f1))
matplot(m123_prob, type = "l", lty = 1)
```

### statistical method (sampling based method)

```
f2 <- function (sample_size) {
  x <- rpois(sample_size, 2)
  ## unbiased estimate of E[x]
  m1 <- mean(x)
  ## unbiased estimate of E[x ^ 2]
  m2 <- mean(x ^ 2)
  ## unbiased estimate of E[x ^ 3]
  m3 <- mean(x ^ 3)
  ## return
  c(m1, m2, m3)
  }
```

As `sample_size` grows, **estimation** is more and more accurate, in the sense that the sequence converges in probability.

```
sample_size <- seq(10, 200, 10)
m123_stat <- t(sapply(sample_size, f2))
matplot(m123_stat, type = "l", lty = 1)
```